# How to import GIT repository into another one, with history?

Tags: git

I would like to embed one repository into another one, in a fashion similar to how github handles project pages.

The base idea is to create orphaned branch (without parents):

```
git clone myproject myproject_folder
cd myproject_folder
git co --orphan project2
git rm -rf . # Remove everything from current index
```

To make github project page, you just name orphaned branch `gh-pages` and start committing to it. Now I would like in this state include another git tracked project, with history.

The expected outcome would be:

```
git clone mymultipleprojects folder
cd folder
git co master  # Master project
git co second  # Completely different, or just related project
```

I know that I can just copy other projects files and commit this, but then I would loose history, can I somehow preserve history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add another repository as an additional origin:

```
git remote add branch-to-merge URL
```

And pull it into your `master` branch:

```
git pull branch-to-merge master
```

Or, in new versions of GIT, the previous command may be run (from the branch you want to pull the changes into) as follows:

```
git merge branch-to-merge --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Comment: Nice and simple, did exactly what I needed. Thanks for the simple and succinct answer!

Comment: This answer is not working anymore since git 2.9, but it can be easily resolved by adding the `--allow-unrelated-histories` parameter to the pull statement to make it `git pull branch-to-merge master --allow-unrelated-histories`.